# Fastest property injection in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of property names = `['prop1', 'prop2',...]`.

And I need to inject them as standard properties into object `obj`, without specifying any values, i.e. `undefined`.

What is the most efficient/performant way to do that?

And would it make any difference when creating `obj` with only those properties somehow?

Comment: Have you tried and compared any options yet?

Comment: ^^ what Jeroen said. Also: Why would it possibly matter?

Comment: I tried a head-on approach of adding those properties in a loop, but thought there could be a better one, maybe something within ES6.

Comment: Can't think of any additions in ES2016 (ES6) that would make this faster. More concise, possibly, but not faster. While you can do a destructuring assignment from an array to an object, you'd have to list the props by name, so that wouldn't help. The only other options I can think of will involve function calls, which while *really really really really fast* are unlikely to rival a boring `for` loop. Probably really close, but...

Comment: If you care about performance it would be better to initialize properties with `null`. I guess that initial value is a placeholder for future values, and null is better for that purposes, because it is easier to compiler make a class from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect your *fastest* option will be a simple `for` loop running backward to 0:

```
let obj = {};
for (let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    obj[array[i]] = undefined;
}
```

But unless you've run into a *real-world performance problem*, it's likely to be premature optimization.

Comment: Most likely it's not only premature optimisation, but rather misguided optimisation. The speed of loops depends a lot on the runtime, and I'd rather use a more standard looping construct that is easier to optimise for the compiler.

Comment: @Bergi: `for` loops with a simple counter variable are as standard as it gets. Very much an easy target for compiler optimization.

Comment: But which one? `for (var i=array.length; i--;)` or `for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++)` are standard as well. Admittedly, I don't understand compilers well enough to know how fuzzy the patterns may be that they are able to optimise.

Comment: @Bergi: Not going to have any trouble with any of those. Very much "low hanging fruit" from an optimization standpoint. These days, you'd want to hope `array.forEach(name => { obj[name] = undefined; });` would run just as quickly. Not *quite*, apparently, on Chrome; Firefox manages it (well, within measurement error), though: http://jsperf.com/for-vs-foreach-when-creating-props Which is really nice to see.